# Cross Validation and training set

Tags: classification, data-mining, cross-validation

In RapidMiner I want to create a k-NN model in order to create a classifier. To generate the test sets and the training sets I use the the cross-validation.

If I choose 10 as the number of folds, the cross-validation algorithm will do 10 iterations with different test sets and training sets.

At the end, what training set will be used to create my k-NN model ?

Comment: The classifier is trained with the whole dataset. The cross-validation folding is done in order to have a statistical measure of the "quality" of the model, For instance, you set K=3 and some certain distance, then, with the 10-fold-CV you have an average accuracy of the model given these parameters, and the final classifier should be one which has been trained with the whole training set.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from having an average accuracy of the trained model, also you can use cross-validation to approximate the optimal value for the k parameter and the optimal metric.

Comment: This generalises to the more common use of cross-validation to tune algorithm hyperparameters.